# Разбить url на массив параметров и значений

Tags: url, php

Как разбить url все что после знака ? на имя и значение?

Вот такая вот ссылка

```
?x=1&y=1;2&z=a;b;c
```

Вот нужно получить

```
x => 1
y => 1;2
z => a;b;c
```

Может есть что стандартное, чтоб не изобретать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Для разбора `url` есть функция [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php). Она делит url на составные части и пишет их в ассоциативный массив. После выполнения:

```
$result=parse_url('http://localhost/?a=1&b=2&c=3');
```

`$result['query']` будет содержать `a=1&b=2&c=3`.

Для разбора url-параметров есть функция [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php). После выполнения:

```
parse_str('a=1&b=2&c=3',$params);
```

В `$params` будет ассоциативный массив с параметрами.

Answer (score 2):

Может не понял в чем проблема, но у вас и так все в массиве будет, только [массив суперглобальный](http://www.php.ru/manual/language.variables.superglobals.html):

```
$_GET['x'] => 1
$_GET['y'] => 2
$_GET['z'] => a;b;c
```

Answer (score 2):

[parse_str](http://php.net/parse-str)

> parse_str — Parses the string into variables

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

Answer (score 1):

$_GET['x'] - это стандартный доступ к переменным, переданным подобным образом.

Если ссылка является просто текстовой строкой - разбивайте по ключевым символам

- [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php);
- [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Answer (score 1):

Можно из глобального массива $_GET для удобства ещё присвоить эти значения переменным:

```
$x = $_GET['x'];
$y = $_GET['x'];
$z = $_GET['z'];
```